# How to extract JSON objects in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am having some problems push values from a `JSON` object. Here is my code

```
try {
     JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(data);
     lat = mainObject.getString("lat");
     lng = mainObject.getString("lon");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is an example of a `JSON` string I will use.

```
{
  "resource":[ 
    {
      "lat":"15.456082",
      "lon":"75.020660",
      "devid":"TEST",
      "time":"2019-03-12 11:11:20",
      "speed":"0.51856",
      "pInt":"60",
      "result":"SOS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use gson

https://github.com/google/gson

it saves lot of time

Comment: Please check my answer and if it is valid then please accept the answer and also upvote. Thanks.

Comment: check out https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest-android

Comment: @sandeep naroti Where do you get this json - it is a response from a network call, is it hardcoded json you need to parse. can you explain the bigger picture so we will be able to fine tune our answers

Comment: @soosita yes it is response from a network call

Comment: @sandeepnaroti if so, you can use libraries such as retrofit in order to map your json responses into java objects. have a look at this simple tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
     JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(data);
     JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("resource");
     JSONObject resourceObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
     String lat = resourceObject.getString("lat");
     String lng = resourceObject.getString("lon");
     String devid = resourceObject.getString("devid");
     String time = resourceObject.getString("time");
     String speed = resourceObject.getString("speed");
     String pInt = resourceObject.getString("pInt");
     String result = resourceObject.getString("result");
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i need to parse all the above  JSON values not only lat lon

Comment: Use google's Gson instead of JSON to parse any Json value. Because if your json is in JsonString format then JSON will not able to remove all unnecessary backslash where Gson can properly. I have posted a correct example of using Gson in below post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
   JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(data);
   JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("resource");
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++ ){
    JSONObject obj= josnArray.getJsonObject(i);
    String lat = obj.getString("lat");
    String lng = obj.getString("lon");
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's Gson instead. Here is full solution. It is life saving.

```
    try {

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(data).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("resource");
        jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String lat = jsonObject.get("lat").getAsString();
        String lng = jsonObject.get("lon").getAsString();

    } catch (JsonIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```